# filter List Object contains value

Tags: dart

```
class Lesson {
  int idLesson;
  String nameLesson;
  List<DayLesson> dayLesson;
  Lesson({this.idLesson, this.dayLesson, this.nameLesson});
}

class DayLesson {
  int idDay;
  String nameDay;
  DayLesson({this.idDay, this.nameDay});
}

List<DayLesson> listDay = [
  DayLesson(idDay: 1, nameDay: 'Monday'),
  DayLesson(idDay: 2, nameDay: 'Tuesday'),
  DayLesson(idDay: 3, nameDay: 'Wednesday'),
  DayLesson(idDay: 4, nameDay: 'Thursday'),
  DayLesson(idDay: 5, nameDay: 'Friday'),
  DayLesson(idDay: 6, nameDay: 'Saturday'),
  DayLesson(idDay: 7, nameDay: 'Sunday'),
];

List<Lesson> listLesson = [
  Lesson(
    idLesson: 1,
    nameLesson: 'Matematic',
    dayLesson: [
      DayLesson(idDay: 1, nameDay: 'Monday'),
      DayLesson(idDay: 5, nameDay: 'Friday'),
    ],
  ),
  Lesson(
    idLesson: 2,
    nameLesson: 'Indonesia Language',
    dayLesson: [
      DayLesson(idDay: 2, nameDay: 'Tuesday'),
      DayLesson(idDay: 4, nameDay: 'Thursday'),
    ],
  ),
  Lesson(
    idLesson: 3,
    nameLesson: 'Chemistry',
    dayLesson: [
      DayLesson(idDay: 3, nameDay: 'Wednesday'),
    ],
  ),
  Lesson(
    idLesson: 4,
    nameLesson: 'Physics',
    dayLesson: [
      DayLesson(idDay: 4, nameDay: 'Thursday'),
      DayLesson(idDay: 5, nameDay: 'Friday'),
    ],
  ),
  Lesson(
    idLesson: 5,
    nameLesson: 'Basic Invesment',
    dayLesson: [
      DayLesson(idDay: 1, nameDay: 'Monday'),
    ],
  ),
];
```

In above code i have 2 class named `Lesson` and `DayLesson`. I want search in `List<Lesson>` where in this list contain day with ID X. Something like `listLesson.where((element)=>element.dayLesson.contain(1)).toList()`.

My expectation with above example will return 2 data , because in listDay have ID with value 1 :

```
[
Lesson(
    idLesson: 1,
    nameLesson: 'Matematic',
    dayLesson: [
      DayLesson(idDay: 1, nameDay: 'Monday'),
      DayLesson(idDay: 5, nameDay: 'Friday'),
    ],
  ),
  Lesson(
    idLesson: 5,
    nameLesson: 'Basic Invesment',
    dayLesson: [
      DayLesson(idDay: 1, nameDay: 'Monday'),
    ],
  ),
]
```

But the problem is, I always get empty list. Is my structure `List` is the problem or am I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't thing [contains](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html) is a correct way to do it. Since you have a List nested inside a List, you will have to nest [where](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) and [any](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/any.html) operations.

```
List<Lesson> _findLessons(int dayLessonId) {
   return listLesson
          .where((element)=> element.dayLesson.any((dL) => dL.idDay == dayLessonId))
          .toList();
}
```

Comment: Already tested in dartpad and return what i expected . Anyway i want know  when method `any` would be very usefull ? i familiar with `firstWhere` compared it. And those method will return the object

Comment: `any` and `firstWhere` are essentially the same. They both return on first instance of the matcher(predicate) to be true. Its just that `any` returns a ***boolean*** if the matcher matches with any instance in the list and `firstWhere` returns the ***instance*** of the list when it matches.